KeyCloak Multitenency
I want to create 2 tenants in a single realm with complete isolation so that one tenant admin can only see/manage his users  and not the other tenants . What would be the best way to achieve this ?
I have tried client+group combination but somehow now able to get it to work properly

As far as I know, realms are intended for tenants. So I would recommend you to use different realms for different tenants.

after reading a few things online, it looks like in the long realm per tenant would be difficult to scale, so we wanted to try this out aswell

There's a preview feature called Fine grain admin permissions. You need to configure the server to enable this and the configuration doesn't seem very simple, maybe this will work for you?

yes that was one of the things I explored , but as you said configuration is not simple , I am not able to find any proper documentation as per my needs
